# a dell tablet has a 36Wh 7.4v battery pack with 2 Li Ion inside the pack,Will the tablet work if one of the batteries are dead or removed?

Tags: battery

I have a dell portable tablet the charging station got broken and some how one of the batteries inside the battery pack got damaged so i took the battery pack appart and removed one of the two batteries,will the tablet work but mabey for a shorter period of time with just one battery in the pack or will it need both to power it ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely won't work at all.

Li-ion batteries provide about 3.7 V per cell. With two of these connected in series you get 7.4 V. You've probably removed one cell, so the circuit is now open and provides no power at all.

I wouldn't recommend messing with batteries without at least basic understanding of electronics.